# Imagemagick: converting gif to pngs and pngs to gif produce different results

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am getting some problems trying to convert a gif file to pngs (change some colors in the pngs, but not yet) and then reconvert it into gif.
I convert the gif using: `convert loading_32.gif loading.png`. It produces 11 pngs files, what is pretty fine. But when I am trying to convert these pngs files into gif again using `convert -delay 10 -loop 0 *.png loading2.gif` , I get a different gif. Here the links to the gifs: [original gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvCDl.gif) and [generated gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWofv.gif)

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `*.png` doesn't add the images in the original order. Try the following...

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 loading-{0..11}.png loading2.gif
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please something else: do you know any way I could convert the pngs files without having to specify each color in the png ? I actually use something like this: `convert loading-0.png -fuzz 10% -fill "#ff0000" -opaque "#5677ACFF" loading-0.png` to change #5677ACFF into #ff0000 but I have to know each color present in the png file. Thanks!

Comment: If you know the X,Y coordinates, then [Draw Color Fill](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#color) might work.  `convert in.png -fuzz 10% -fill '#ff0000' -draw 'color 20,30 filltoborder' out.png`